# Bootstrap modal doesn't work when modal defined outside of vue instance

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, vue.js, bootstrap-modal

I am trying to open up a bootstrap modal from within a vue instance.

The function works if I find the modal element within the function. However, if I declare the modal element as a variable either outside the instance or in the vue data object the modal is broken (the backdrop appears but I can't see the modal).

Here is my code:

```
<div id="app">
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
          <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          ...
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <button class="btn btn-default" data-target="#myModal" @click="makeNormalModal">Normal Modal</button>
  <button class="btn btn-danger" data-target="#myModal" @click="makeBrokenModal">Broken Modal</button>
</div>
```

and the javascript:

```
let modalElement = $('#myModal');

const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    'modal': $('#myModal')
  },
  methods: {
    makeNormalModal() {
      let element = $(event.target);
      $('#myModal').modal('show');
    },
    makeBrokenModal() {
      this.modal.modal('show');
    }
  }
});
```

I have created a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ukmnc4gs/1/) to show the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [`ref`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#ref) attribute:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" ref="modal">
```

Then, access it via [`$refs`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-refs) property:

```
$(this.$refs.modal).modal('show');
```

Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ukmnc4gs/4/

Answer (score 0):

Instead of $('#myModal') set '#myModal' inside your `data` object.

```
const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    'modal': '#myModal'
  },
  methods: {
      makeBrokenModal(event) {
        $(this.modal).modal('show')
      }
  }
});
```